# Trouble with casting a type

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I have come across an issue whereby I am unable to cast my class to its parent type and unsure of why this is considering the end product is the same... Is it because the class is abstract or because of the generic type specified in the constructor? However, I would of thought the constraint on the class would of resolved that?

Sorry if I haven't explained this well but I think the code below may demonstrate the issue in greater detail.

Thanks in advance, Onam.

```
public abstract class ClaimRepository<T> where T : WarrantyClaimBase 
{
    public ClaimRepository()
    { }

    public ClaimRepository(bool IncludeLabour, bool IncludeFranchiseLabour)
    {
    }

    protected abstract void GetFranchiseLabour();
}

public class TestClaimRepository : ClaimRepository<GWMWarrantyClaim>
{
    public TestClaimRepository()
    { }
    protected override void GetFranchiseLabour()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Custom Implementation");
    }
}

public sealed class Factory
{
    public Factory()
    { }

    public ClaimRepository<WarrantyClaimBase> Get()
    {
        return new TestClaimRepository();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting?  Is it a compile error or a runtime error?

Comment: Why is your class generic when you don't use T anywhere?

Comment: I assume `GWMWarrantyClaim` inherits from `WarrantyClaimBase `?

Comment: @Strillo it has to because the abstract class also has that constraint.

Comment: Why is your `Factory` not static?

Comment: Why does `Factory.Get()` have a `T`? It doesn't use it anywhere inside.

Comment: Sorry guys, yup that was a school boy by me (I left it in by accident). But I am wondering why I can't cast TestClaimRepository to my ClaimRepository as TestClaimRepository inherits it?

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you're getting an error from `Factory.Get<T>()`. You have a constraint that says T must inherit from WarrantyClaimBase but you're returning a more specific type. Think about what would happen if I wrote:

```
var factory = new Factory();
factory.Get<SomeOtherWarrantyType>();
```

The code is valid since `SomeOtherWarrantyType` inherits from `WarrantyClaimBase` but `TestClaimRepository` obviously can't be cast to a `ClaimRepository<SomeOtherWarrantyType>`. I would suggest changing your definition of `Get()` to since you're not using `T` anyway:

```
public ClaimRepository<WarrantyClaimBase> Get() { }
```

Comment: +1 Good explanation and no reason to use a generic parameter in this case.

Comment: Yeah its the Factory.Get() method that is causing me the problem but by changing it to returning a ClaimRepository<WarrantyClaimBase> it is not returning the type that I actually want... I thought because the TestClaimRepository is inheriting ClaimRepository it should be castable?

Comment: @Onam - You can cast TestClaimRepository to WarrantyClaimBase, but as in my example...you can't cast TestClaimReository to ClaimRepository which is what would happen if you ran my example.

Comment: Why isn't that allowed considering it inherits from it? I can go about it in a different way by placing these constraints on methods instead of the class but this seem appears to be more cleaner to me...

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are getting the compile error here:

```
public ClaimRepository<WarrantyClaimBase> Get()
{
    return new TestClaimRepository();
}
```

The problem is that `TestClaimRepository` inherits from `ClaimRepository<GWMWarrantyClaim>`, which does not inherit from `ClaimRepository<WarrantyClaimBase>`.

In fact, `ClaimRepository<GWMWarrantyClaim>` inherits from object and is no more related to `ClaimRepository<WarrantyClaimBase>` than it is to `string` from the inheritance hierarchy point of view.

You seem to have the assumption that `T : U` implies `M<T> : M<U>` for a generic type M.  This is never true for classes. (If ClaimRepository were an interface, you may be able to get away with this.  I recommend reading about covariance in .NET)